# Php - Error messages show up even when they are irrelevant

Tags: php

Im trying upload code and I cant find out how to make errors to show only if its true. Because now for example if file is not image, shows me all possible errors. "File is not an image.Sorry, your file is too large.Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.Sorry, your file was not uploaded." Everything is fine, except im tryin to upload not image. I want it show me only errors there is, not all possible errors. So I want it shows now onlySorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed. Dont want it shows your file is too large, even if its not too large. How do I do? Here is full code:

```
    <?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {enter code here
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

P.S Im total begginer of coding :)

Comment: Link all the conditions with else. Actually being indipendent they all evaluate to true in your example. Chained by else your code will stop at the first true

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it when there are many potential errors is to use an array.

```
$errors = array();
```

Then you just assign errors to the array, as you go along, e.g.

```
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
  $errors[] = "Sorry, file already exists.";
}
```

Then you can display the errors in any way you'd like.

**Note**
This assumes that your error handling is correct from the start. Judging from your text, you aren't expecting all the errors. Go through if-statement per if-statement to check that it in fact works, e.g. if you upload a file with a unique name, but `if (file_exists($target_file))` still works out as `true`, then go over that piece of code again.

Answer (score 0):

Search through your file. Everything that says echo, remove it; and leave only the values you want. Like on line 13 it says

```
    echo "File is not an image.";
```

remove that line of code, and you won't see "File is not an image." anymore

Comment: The hell dude? :D I wanted to ask how to show errors only when it should show.. I want to see File is not an image, but only when its true, not only when 1 of any errors true then its showing all possible errors.

Comment: OK make a variable at the beginning of of your PHP script. Let's give it a name; we'll call it $errors. start with <?php $errors = ""; everytime you see echo, replace it with $errors = $errors . "File is not an image"; or $errors = $errors . "File is not a JPEG"; at the end of the script echo $errors; also one escape route would be to use die(); if there is an error. It'll stop the entire script from continuing..

Comment: If my answer helped you, please +1 it. I took my time out to help you; press the button and help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The errors are cascading. Stop error checking after the first error ie..

```
if ($uploadOk AND file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

You may also need to change the order in which the errors are checked if the wrong error is being returned